# Proof of floor and ceiling functions

Tags: proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

By definition:

$ \lfloor {x}\rfloor = i \Rightarrow i \le x \lt i + 1 $ (floor function)

and

$ \lceil {x} \rceil  = j \Rightarrow j - 1 \lt x \le j $ (ceiling function)

So, how is the proof that these properties are true for all integers?

$(n−1)/2  ≤  ⌊n/2⌋  ≤  n/2$

$n/2  ≤  ⌈n/2⌉  ≤  (n+1)/2$

Comment: Write $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$ for an integer $k$ and consider the two cases separately?

Comment: When $n = 2k$ on first: $(2k -1)/2 ≤ ⌊k⌋ ≤ k$ and with n = 2k + 1: $k ≤ ⌊2k+ 1⌋ ≤ 2k+ 1$
Right? How consider all cases now?

Comment: The floor function on an integer is the integer itself. So the two equations you wrote up (which you need to prove) become $(2k -1)/2 ≤ k ≤ k$ and $k ≤ 2k+ 1 ≤ 2k+ 1$.

Comment: Your ceiling definition should be $j-1<x\le j$. To check, note ceiling of an integer should be itself.

Comment: @coffeemath Sure... Edited =)

Comment: Did you follow HHO's hint?